# Creation and Usage of TimerTask: How not to have circular dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, timer, timertask

I am working with Eclipse Luna and WildFly 8.2.1.Final.

I have an Enterprise Application project named **P001_EAR** which consist of:

1. A `Dynamic Web Project` named **P001_WAR**.
2. An `EJB Project` named **P001_EJB**.
3. An `EJB Client Project` named **P001_EJBClient**.
4. An `Utility Project` named **P001_SRC**.

This is how each project references:

- **P001_SRC** does not reference any other project.
- **P001_EJB** references **P001_SRC** and **P001_EJBClient**.
- **P001_EJBClient** references **P001_SRC**.
- **P001_WAR** references **P001_SRC** and **P001_EJBClient**.

Note: In **P001_WAR** I have 1 `Business Delegate` for each EJB which call EJB methods of that EJB.

---

I need to create a `java.util.TimerTask` class which will be scheduled to run (the schedule information like first time and frequency is in database). On each run it will call couple of methods of an EJB. This is what I come up with:

```
public final class FirstTimerTask extends TimerTask {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      // get EJB1
      // call method of EJB1
      // call another method of EJB1
   }
}
```

I need to create a class which will create 1 or more `java.util.TimerTask` class and schedule them. It will have the `java.util.Timer`. The schedule information of a task is in database which I was hoping to get through an EJB. This is what I come up with:

```
public final class ScheduleTasksManager {
   private static Timer TIMER = new TIMER();

   public static void scheduleFirstTimerTask() {
      TimerTask timerTask = null;
      Date taskStartDate = null;
      long period = -1;
      // get EJB2
      // call method of EJB2 to retrieve the schedule information from database and populate taskStartDate and period
      timerTask = new FirstTimerTask();
      TIMER.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, taskStartDate, period);
   }
}
```

My question is where to put `FirstTimerTask` and `ScheduleTasksManager` classes so that I dont have any circular dependencies? I am stumped.

I think `FirstTimerTask` would need to be in a project which has reference to **P001_EJBClient** as it needs to call EJB.

I think `ScheduleTasksManager` would need to be in a project which has reference to **P001_EJBClient** as it needs to call EJB.

Comment: Can you draw a diagram to show what you did?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I have not write those 2 classes `FirstTimerTask` and `ScheduleTasksManager` yet. This is pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule you should not be using [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) objects in an enterprise java application because the resources they consume are not under the control of your application server.

Java EE 7 provides you with scheduling and other concurrency constructs for doing these types of operation in controlled fashion.

The following is an example of a Java EE way of achieving your goal. There's no circular dependencies here:

FirstTimer.java

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerConfig;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

@Stateless
public class FirstTimer {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @EJB
    private Ejb2 ejb2;

    @EJB
    private Ejb1 ejb1;

    /* 
     * Call this from somewhere to start the timer.
     * Use the returned Timer object to cancel it if needed.
     */
    public Timer scheduleTask() {
        final Calendar start = ejb2.getStartDate();
        final long period = ejb2.getPeriodInMillisecs();
        return timerService.createIntervalTimer(start.getTime(), period, new TimerConfig(null, false));
    }

    @Timeout
    public void handleTimeout() {
        ejb1.method1();
        ejb1.method2();
    }

}
```

Ejb1.java

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class Ejb1 {

    public void method1() {
    }

    public void method2() {
    }
}
```

Ejb2.java

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class Ejb2 {

    public Calendar getStartDate() {
        Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDate.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
        return startDate;
    }

    public long getPeriodInMillisecs() {
        return Duration.ofMinutes(2L).toMillis();
    }
}
```

There's more fun stuff over at [Using the Timer Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

Comment: Thanks. This helps me a lot. Although I am currently working with EJB 2.1 but still your solution give me idea on how to implement it with EBJ 2.1.